# Networking option in VMware workstation

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, nat

I am trying to setup something like a VPS on my computer. What I will do is:

1) Install vmware workstation on my computer

2) Install linux ubuntu as the operating system

3) Setup a vpn software inside whereby there is a need for connection to the internet via a private IP (provided by the VPN service provider)

My question here is since this is a complete new virtual machine installation on my computer, with a unique IP used when connection to the internet, which networking option (bridged, nat or host-only) should I used when setting up vmware so that anyone would not be able to track or trace back there is a relationship/ linkage between the virtual machine and the host (my computer)? Would anyone be able to trace/ track that there is a link between the virtual machine and my computer when I connect to the internet inside the virtual machine (via a different IP, proxy, etc)? In this case, which networking option (bridged, nat or host-only) should I use when my primary objective is accessing the web inside the virtual machine, no major or complicated applications.

Answer (score 1):

Host only network: it connects the vmware to the host private network, but cannot connect directly to the external network. This will make use of the host ip address in a private network.

NAT: will connect directly to the host and can connect directly to the external network. Will It shares the host ip address in external communication.

Bridged: this will require a physical NIC (network interface card) because the host ip address isn't used in this case.